# How do you enter Harper's Ferry?

Tags: fallout-76

In an effort to unlock as many vendor factions as possible (to have as many 200 cap pools available each day), I went out of my way to head to Harper's Ferry early, as there is a vendor faction unique to this location. However, upon arrival, I could not find a way into the walled-off section of the town, where I believe the vendor bot resides.

The only way I could feasibly find in were several level 3 lock pick doors (which I am too low level to pick), and several large red "garage door" sized entries that were sealed and could not be interacted with. I'm aware that this location is tied to a main story questline mission (which I have not reached yet), but I was under the impression that a specific location/building inside Harper's Ferry, not the whole walled-in area, was locked out to this. Is there a way to enter Harper's Ferry at this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Travel to Harpers Ferry
2. Go down the street looking to the right.
3. Go up the stairs, jump down halfway.
4. cross street and go the ladder on the roof up and turn left.
5. Straight ahead the vendor is placed

*Will put some screenshots once I'm home*

Comment: Somehow missed the entrance through the wrecked train towards the back (Northeast) of that area... fast travel brings you pretty close to that part, so coming back this time was easier finding it. Thanks!